# SQLAlchemy listener on query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create an event listener for a database model in SQLAlchemy that can modify all objects that are queried every time they are queried?

For example, if I have the model:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}_{}".format(self.id, self.email)
```

and I wanted to eliminate any user that is over a year old, is there a way I can run a function every time the User model is queried, and only for the queried users?

Comment: Could you specify what you need exactly, and also what you've already tried ?  Looks like you need a custom query class for your model instead of an event ?  Something that could filter directly the users...

Comment: How the `User` model queried? `select`, `update`, etc.?